# Visual Studio 2013 runtime text template for assembly properties

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying (so far unsuccessfully) to use a runtime text template to set the year on the AssemblyCopyright property.  I want to do this to automate this process so we don't have to think about it (boss wants it updated every time we release in a new year).  The content of the file is as follows:

```
<#@ template language="C#" #>
using System;
using System.Reflection;

[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright (c) <#=year#> My Company, Inc.")]
<#+
    String year = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();
#>
```

I used this file and commented out the corresponding line from AssemblyInfo.cs.  When the project is compiled, the program properties only show a blank for Copyright.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using a ***runtime** text template* (custom tool = *TextTemplatingFilePreprocessor*), where the text is transformed at runtime, you need to change it to just a *text template* (custom tool = *TextTemplatingFileGenerator*).